# Прозрачность блока при прокрутке вниз

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так, чтобы `navbar` становился прозрачным при прокрутке вниз?
Использую *bootstrap*.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><span>qwerty</span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="health.html">qwerty</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">qwerty</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">qwerty</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">qwerty</a></li>                 
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>  
</nav>
```

Comment: А при прокрутке вверх обратно становился видимым?

Comment: Да. Чтобы был видимым только в самой верхней точке.

Comment: Может тогда просто убрать класс `navbar-fixed-top`?

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы он был зафиксированным

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Делается это с помощью события `onscroll`, которое нужно применить к `window`, и проверкой на положение скролла

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  var scrolled = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop; // Получаем положение скролла
  if(scrolled !== 0){
    // Если прокрутка есть, то делаем блок прозрачным
    document.querySelector('.navbar').style.opacity = '0.5';
  }else{
    // Если нет, то делаем его полностью видимым
    document.querySelector('.navbar').style.opacity = '1';
  };
};
```

```css
body {height: 2000px}

.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Ещё вопрос: как поменять степень прозрачности?

Comment: @Ravdan, эмм... а значение `0.5` и `1` - это что по-вашему?)

Comment: Уже понял. Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: А какой код нужно ввести, чтобы при нажатии на гамбургер navbar снова становился полностью видимым?

Comment: @Ravdan, эмм... вы вообще JS учили?

Comment: Учил. Всего не запомнишь.

Comment: @Ravdan, ничего вы не учили. Это основы. Это самое первое, что нужно знать. Задавайте новый вопрос по этому поводу и вам ответят